# How to put a default image if img tag is empty using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do is put a default image file in the img tag if it is `empty` or the user havent uploaded his picture yet.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3117/

html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <img id="Picture" data-src="#" alt="your image" /> <br />
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
</form>
```

script:

```
$(function () {
    var loader = 'http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/profile_male_large_zpseedb2954.jpg';
    $('img[data-src]:not([src])').each(function () {
        console.log(this);
        var $img = $(this).attr('src', loader),
            src  = $img.data('src'),
            $clone = $img.clone().attr('src', src);
        $clone.on('load', function () {
            $img.attr('src', src);
        });
    });
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: It is a duplicate of that but I prefer this answer to the one that was selected http://stackoverflow.com/a/168448/822711

Comment: @Popnoodles yeah it's simpler to use that option

Comment: Could it be as easy as setting the img src to the default image and overriding it only if the user provides/has uploaded an image?